# How do all the networking services fit together?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, systemd

I am struggling a little with understanding what all the different networking systems do. On my Fedora workstation, everything "just works", but I am running Debian on a Raspberry Pi and I slowly losing overview of which service / setting does what.

On that rPi, I have three systems running that manage network interfaces (CMIIW): `dhcpcd`, `networking` and `systemd-networkd`. By default, `dhcpcd` handles the IP address assignment, but those other ones are also active in `systemd`.

For example, for what I understand, `systemd-networkd` uses `.network` files in `/etc/systemd/network` to manage the network (IP addresses, SSID, DHCP, etc). But so is `dhcpcd` using `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

So, my question is, how does this all fit together? Which service is doing what and how do they not bite each other?